# Join table vs Join Subquery - which is more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I was recently going through a lot of SQL code where Join sections were filled with complex subqueries, and started wondering if there is any benefit of joining subquery with limited column selection vs joining entire table and selecting only necessary columns.

**To ilustrate that:**

Let's say we have 2 tables: `Table1, Table2` each with columns `(PK, FK, a, b ,c, d, e, f)`.
I want to join Table1 with Table2, but retrieve only a few fields from Table2.

Which is more efficient, what are the benefits of each?

```
SELECT 
  Table1.*,
  Table2.a,
  Table2.b

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PK = Table2.FK
```

OR

```
SELECT
  Table1.*,
  Table2sub.*

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK, a, b FROM Table2) AS Table2sub ON Table1.PK = Table2sub.FK
```

Comment: *"Which is more efficient"* testing the statements would give you that answer pretty quickly. What did you find?

Comment: If you accept Gordon's answer with regard to performance, what remains to be noted is that the first one is *much* easier to read

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis that's the thing - I thought that poor readability must be a sacrifice for some gain (probably efficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  That is, a SQL query describes what the result set looks like, not *how* the result is produced.

In fact, what the engine runs is called a directed acyclic graph (DAG) -- and that looks nothing like a query.  The SQL engine first parses the query, then compiles it, then optimizes it to produce the DAG.

SQL Server has a good optimizer.  It is not going to be confused by subqueries.  Some SQL compilers are not quite as smart and will materialize the subquery -- which could have a big impact on performance.

If you look at the execution plans, you will see that they are the same in this case.